# Convert SVG Co-ordinates to HTML Image Map Co-ordinates

Tags: html, svg, imagemap, area

I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/7669029/1223045 's instructions to automate the process of plotting co-ordinates on an image and was successful in generating the `SVG` co-ordinates for a area.

Now in order to use the same co-ordinates in `area` map, I will need to convert it to its equivalent format and this is where I'm struggling.

I came across a python [**script**](http://davidlynch.org/blog/2008/03/creating-an-image-map-from-svg/) which does the conversion process, but since I have no idea about python, I don't know how to use it or how to proceed ahead with it.

Are there any other alternatives aside from the above script?

Answer (score 0):

To translate svg coordinates must take each coordinate and move it to a total displacement figures , groups and all svg.
Sample code for translation in svg map area:

```
$ coord = "";
$ x = $ offset_x * $ scale_x + $ translate_x;
$ y = $ offset_y * $ scale_y + $ translate_y;
foreach ($ coordinates [ 1 ] as $ k => $ a) {
if ($ k% 2 == 0) {
$ coord. = round ($ x). ",";
$ x + = $ a * $ scale_x;
} else {
$ coord. = round ($ y). ",";
$ y + = $ a * $ scale_y;
}
}
$ coord = substr ($ coord, 0, -1) ;
```

Where translate x / y and scale x / y refer to g, and offset x / y coordinates of the starting offset figure.
In general then svg coordinates are written in the normal form , the main thing to take into account all the offsets and the fact that svg coordinates considered each of the previous one, but in all map area coordinates are taken from the origin.